# Updating a dataframe with boolean sub-indexing

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe, and I want to replace any entries higher than 1 with 1. The dataframe has several dtypes (strings, numbers and dates) so:

```
df.gt(1.2)
```

returns:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'view'
```

If I do:

```
df[cols].gt(1.2) # where cols are a specific subset of df.columns
```

I get back a **boolean subset** of the original dataframe where entries are higher than `1.2`.  However, if I try to use this result to update my original dataframe, it wouldn't work:

```
df.ix[df[cols].gt(1.2), cols] = 1 # This doesn't update the dataframe the right way
```

How can I update my original dataframe?

Note: This is all with `0.13.1`

```
> df.dtypes
year                            int64
week                            int64
item_name                      object
item_uid                       object
algorithm                      object
item start                    float64
item 1/4                      float64
item 1/2                      float64
item 3/4                      float64
item complete                 float64
daily data                    float64
date                   datetime64[ns]
weekly rate                   float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: I think this is a bug because if you compare to `array([1.2])` instead you get back the expected result.

Comment: Thanks @PhillipCloud Regarding the possibility of using `array([1.2])`. If I try: `df[df.gt(np.array([1.2]))] = 1` I get: `TypeError: Cannot do boolean setting on mixed-type frame`.

Comment: You still need to select out the numeric columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could always do something like this.

```
df.update((df[cols] > 1.2).replace((True, False), (1, np.nan))
```

Comment: You can't call the `replace` method on the result of `DataFrame.update()` because it returns `None` and `None` has only dunder methods.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the `_get_numeric_data()` method. I'd recommend against depending on an internal method, but it turns out to be useful in this case:

```
In [67]: df = DataFrame(randn(10, 3))

In [68]: df['b'] = 'c'

In [69]: df['a'] = 'd'

In [70]: df['date'] = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=10)

In [71]: df
Out[71]:
        0       1       2  b  a       date
0 -0.2094 -1.6014  0.4309  c  d 2013-01-01
1  0.5508  0.9743 -0.1097  c  d 2013-01-02
2  0.8589  0.2062 -0.9720  c  d 2013-01-03
3  0.9868 -0.9927 -1.2546  c  d 2013-01-04
4  0.1206  1.4992 -3.1880  c  d 2013-01-05
5 -1.1514 -0.4342  0.4475  c  d 2013-01-06
6  0.3164 -1.3131  0.1723  c  d 2013-01-07
7 -0.2959 -1.2914 -0.6876  c  d 2013-01-08
8 -0.8382  0.1901  0.9898  c  d 2013-01-09
9  0.5659 -1.6537 -0.6423  c  d 2013-01-10

[10 rows x 6 columns]

In [72]: df.dtypes
Out[72]:
0              float64
1              float64
2              float64
b               object
a               object
date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

In [73]: num_data = df._get_numeric_data()

In [74]: df.loc[num_data > 1.2, num_data.columns]
Out[74]:
        0       1       2
0 -0.2094 -1.6014  0.4309
1  0.5508  0.9743 -0.1097
2  0.8589  0.2062 -0.9720

[3 rows x 3 columns]

In [75]: df.loc[num_data > 1.2, num_data.columns] = 1

In [76]: df
Out[76]:
        0       1       2  b  a       date
0  1.0000  1.0000  1.0000  c  d 2013-01-01
1  1.0000  1.0000  1.0000  c  d 2013-01-02
2  1.0000  1.0000  1.0000  c  d 2013-01-03
3  0.9868 -0.9927 -1.2546  c  d 2013-01-04
4  0.1206  1.4992 -3.1880  c  d 2013-01-05
5 -1.1514 -0.4342  0.4475  c  d 2013-01-06
6  0.3164 -1.3131  0.1723  c  d 2013-01-07
7 -0.2959 -1.2914 -0.6876  c  d 2013-01-08
8 -0.8382  0.1901  0.9898  c  d 2013-01-09
9  0.5659 -1.6537 -0.6423  c  d 2013-01-10

[10 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks. I *am* able to run your example, but this solution fails on my dataframe. I am investigating why, but the call to `df._get_numeric_data` returns :`<repr(<pandas.core.frame.DataFrame at 0x11d528cd0>) failed: IndexError: list assignment index out of range>`. Although it doesn't throw any exception.

Comment: @acushner's answer is the only that works in my case. I will try to post some data, but this is really odd.

Comment: Do you have IPython auto reload turned on? I sometimes get strange errors when I rerun some code after editing it.

Comment: Yes. I wonder if this is the problem. I will try turning it off.